# How to make TinyMce replace deprecated tags with inline styles?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am a noob to tinyMce. I want to implement tinymce such that deprecated tags like `strong,b,i,em` are replaced with corresponding inline styles like `'font-weight:bold', etc`.

I tried using custom formats

```
formats : {
     bold: {inline : 'span', 'styles' : 'font-weight:bold'}
}
```

But when I try to apply bold formatting i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'replace' 
(anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
e.create.run tiny_mce.js:1
e.create.setStyle tiny_mce.js:1
(anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
c.each tiny_mce.js:1
ab tiny_mce.js:1
an tiny_mce.js:1
Y tiny_mce.js:1
F tiny_mce.js:1
s tiny_mce.js:1
u.Bold,Italic,Underline,Strikethrough,Superscript,Subscript tiny_mce.js:1
r tiny_mce.js:1
k.create.execCommand tiny_mce.js:1
i.onclick tiny_mce.js:1
(anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
j tiny_mce.js:1
y tiny_mce.js:1
```

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YPaEv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should ought to do it:

```
    formats : {
          bold : {inline : 'span', styles : {fontWeight : 'bold'}},
    }
```